# videowriter function doesnt save the file with opencv-3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am working with `GigaE Camera` and it is a grayscale image and I want to record the videos. So I have tried initially with webcam and below is my code:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp" 
#include "iostream" 
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"
#include<string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

VideoCapture cap(0);
VideoWriter writer;
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "not opened" << endl;
    return -1;
}

char* windowName = "Webcam Feed";
namedWindow(windowName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
string filename = "D:\videos\myVideo12.avi";
int fcc = CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'J');
int fps = 30;
Size frameSize(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
bool isColor = false;
writer = VideoWriter(filename, fcc, fps, frameSize, isColor);

if (!writer.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Error not opened" << endl;
    getchar();
    return -1;
}


while (1)
{

    Mat frame;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);

    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        cout << "ERROR READING FRAME FROM CAMERA FEED" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    writer.write(frame);
    imshow(windowName, frame);
  return 0;
}
```

There is no video created and I don't get any error too. But it works fine with OpenCV-2.4.10.

Comment: `CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'J')` -- That looks like a rather odd FourCC code. Shouldn't that be MJPG?

Comment: Yes, but the file is not created and error is due to the format of the filename. I have used the '\' instead of '/'. Furthermore, the codec MPJG also gives the video but with more noisy and blur video. The codec MPEG gives the better video images.

Comment: Good point, totally missed that string with unescaped backslashes :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the video is not written because of the codec. OpenCV tends to stay silent in case of encoding (and many other) problems. Try setting fcc to -1 to choose from a list of available codecs.

Comment: I tried with -1. Now I get the error of "error not opened". how Do I check the codecs is installed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The error is in the giving the filename path where I used '\' instead of '/'. The codecs are MPEG or DIV3 for grayscale images.